# Why Azure app service VNET integration failing with new subnet?

Tags: azure, vnet

I'm trying to connect my app service plan in to VNET. But always failed. I have red threads and everywhere saying App service plan should be Standard or higher.

1. My App service Plan is S1.
2. It's just an empty app.
3. I'm creating new subnet (not select existing one) when configuring VNET.
4. I have run the trouble-shooter and no issue found with connectivity

Can someone help on this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: App service plan must be a standard or premium or premium V2. Are you using the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was my VNET and App service in different subscription .
But in same region. move app service in to other subscription which contains VNET. Problem solved.

Seems to be VNET integration not working between Resorces in multipole subscriptions .Cheers

Answer (score 0):

> There are some limitations with using regional virtual network integration:

Refer [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#limitations)

1. If you have already one VNet associated with an app service plan, it would be better if you create a new app service plan and then configure the VNet. I found the same fix [here](https://asish.com/configure-vnet-to-the-app-vnet-configuration-failed/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20tried%20to%20integrate%20VNet%20within%20an,use%20it%20with%20the%20new%20Azure%20App%20Service) by @Asish Punnose.
2. **"App service plan, VNet** as well as **App"** should be in the same region.
3. The integration subnet can only use one App Service plan

After considering all the above limitations, I was able to configure VNet successfully.

***By adding a new subnet, enabling inbound & outbound traffic addresses with a new virtual network as well as new app service plan I could create an app with standard s1 plan.***

[image]

***Added subnets under VNet integration:***

[image]

***Configured VNet with an app service plan*** without any error:

[image]

[image]